# pdf image is not visible on production enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am using acts_as_flying_saucer plugin to generate pdf in which i need to show some text and images,It is working fine on local and staging environment.

But on production server image is not getting displayed in pdf, image is present in public folder, have checked it and it is getting displayed in html file which gets created in /tmp folder while generating pdf file.

I have tried with hard coded image also, But image is not getting displayed.

Comment: Does your application have permissions on the image file in the production environment? Does your application on production leave any logs? What do they say?

Comment: yes image file have permission and log file does not show any error.